# adding prefix to NetSuite Sales Order tranid

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We're trying to figure out how we can add prefix to the tranid in NetSuite when Sales Order is created. We have a person who has written a script which works for the first order, but any orders after that get duplicate order number prompt, because NetSuite tries assign previous auto generated number, because technically for NetSuite that number was never used. 
Below is the script written so far, and we'r hopping to get advise how we can resolve this issue?

```
function setEDIPrefix(){
    if(nlapiGetContext().getExecutionContext()=='webservices'&&nlapiGetContext().getUser()==999108){ //user 1646 is my account's SPS user internal id
       var id = nlapiGetFieldValue('tranid'); //gets value from 'document number' field
             nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','Id: '+id);
                   nlapiSetFieldValue('tranid','EDI'+id); //appends "EDI-" prefix to the NetSuite assigned document number
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested, it seems that the auto-generated tranid is incremented once the record is saved, so the solution for your case is to change the tranid in the afterSubmit and not in the beforeSubmit : you can reload the current record, or better use the "[nlapiSubmitField(type, id, fields, values, doSourcing)](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3039111.html#bridgehead_N3042189)" function.

**Side note:** it is time to start using SS2.0 :)

Try this code:

```
if(type == 'create' && nlapiGetContext().getExecutionContext()=='webservices' && nlapiGetContext().getUser() == 999108){ //user 1646 is my account's SPS user internal id
      var id = nlapiGetFieldValue('tranid'); //gets value from 'document number' field
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','Id: '+id);

      nlapiSubmitField(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId(), 'tranid', 'EDI' + id);
  }
```

I added a test on the operation type : you need to do the update only on creation.

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention that we only want EDI  prefix applied when orders are generated via webservices and, plus when created by certain user ( as you can see in my above script)

Comment: Your script is executed as a Client or Userevent script ? And when : beforesubmit ? aftersubmit ?

Comment: Script type is User Event and execute beforesubmit

Comment: Sorry I'm new with NetSuite scripting and just tried updating the execute to aftersumbit, but then script does not run. Do I need to modify the script itself also?

Comment: Yes you need to update : specially the SetValue part : because in the afterSubmit context, the record can be non-editable : that is why I said you need to use nlapiSubmitField.

Comment: Updated my answer with a ss1.0 code that you can use on the afterSubmit (tested).

Comment: One question: I'm able to get this working when creating orders in UI with modified script, but still having the issue when trying to import via webservices using the exact script, except the context. Did you test your's in UI or through webservices?

Comment: I didn't test using webservices, but if it works using UI, it must work using webservice (with changed context condition). When you say it is not working, what happens really ? What error are you getting ?

Comment: Yes, I did updated context accordingly. When importing through web services, transid is assigned by NetSuite like this "EDIUndefined TranId"

Comment: you mean you get something like this EDIUndefined123 ? where 123 is the auto-generated tranid ? past your code here please. Because in my code I just concat EDI + id so I don't know how is it that you have an Undefined

Comment: For testing purposes, I've two scripts and I've past them both here. The UI one works, but the webservices one does not with tranid populating as "EDIUndefined TranId" with no auto generated number.

Comment: UI Code: function setEDIPrefix(){
               if(type == 'create' && nlapiGetContext().getExecutionContext()=='userinterface' && nlapiGetContext().getUser() == 296644){ //user 1646 is my account's SPS user internal id
      var id = nlapiGetFieldValue('tranid'); //gets value from 'document number' field
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','Id: '+id);

      nlapiSubmitField(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId(), 'tranid', 'EDI' + id);
  }
}

Comment: Webservices code:   function setEDIPrefix(){
               if(type == 'create' && nlapiGetContext().getExecutionContext()=='webservices' && nlapiGetContext().getUser() == 999108){ //user 1646 is my account's SPS user internal id
      var id = nlapiGetFieldValue('tranid'); //gets value from 'document number' field
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','Id: '+id);

      nlapiSubmitField(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId(), 'tranid', 'EDI' + id);
  }
}

Comment: Seems strange, I can't test because creating a Webservice test case is complicated, but there is a log in the code where the autogenerated id is logged, what do you see when your run using webservice ? Also, are you sure you don't have another script interfering with this one ?

Answer (score 1):

For those coming to this article looking for an answer, there are several ways to accomplish this, but they all depend on a configuration setting in netsuite.

Step 1.  Enable the `Allow Override` function for auto-generated numbers

In `Setup` > `Company` > `Auto-Generated Numbers`, select the `Document Numbers` tab.  For the `Sales Order` type (or any other transaction type), select `Allow Override`.

Step 2.  Set the `tranid` via webservices, or user event

If you are writing your own integration, you can update the tranid using either REST or SOAP on suitetalk by setting the `tranId` field value on the upsert / save / create operation.  With a user even script, using SuiteScript 2.0, you would use something like the below:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType usereventscript
 */
define(["N/record", "N/log"],
function(r, log) {
  function before_submit(context) {
    log.debug("my awesome user event script", "starting")
    if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE) {
      log.debug("my awesome user event script", "not a create")
      return;
    }
    var sales_order = context.newRecord;
    var order_number = "my awesome tranid";
    log.debug("my awesome user event script", "setting tranid => " + order_number)
    sales_order.setValue('tranid', order_number);
  }
  return {
    beforeSubmit: before_submit
  };
});
```